# Case Statement with Trap (BASH)

Tags: bash

I'm still not quite understand with the concepts of "case" and "trap" statement if they are combined together.

**What I want to do:**

When the trap statement is triggered, it removes every **TMP** (temporary files) that already been created by the script.

However, when I tried to run this code, sometimes the script still left some **TMP** files

```
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then 
    TMP=./TMP$$
    cat $FILENAME > $TMP
    case "$1" in
        -b*)awesomeFunction exit 0;;
        -B*)echo "ERROR!" >&2; exit 1;;
        *)echo "ERROR!" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
    trap "rm -f $TMP" INT HUP TERM
fi
```

**Output example** (after trap statement is triggered)

Correct output:

```
file1   file2
```

My output:

```
file1   file2  TMP23242  TMP24452
```

Did I misplace the trap statement? Anybody can give me an advice how to make the script run the trap statement properly? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use `EXIT` instead of `INT HUP TERM` -- the bash-specific `EXIT` signal will fire the handler no matter how the shell exits, whether by error or by successful completion of the script.

Comment: Also, it won't remove *all* TMP files, just the one that got created by that run of the script.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yeah, that's what I mean. Did I put the trap statement correctly tho?

Comment: Your `if` and `fi` statements aren't balanced. You have more `fi` than `if`.

Comment: I would move the trap statement to the line below `TMP=...`. As mpez0 answered, if your script errors before executing the trap statement, how can it know to run the handler?

Comment: @Barmar: Oh yes, thank you. I guess that's just a typo, because in my statement it is only 1 fi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the trap statement early in your code; the contents will not be executed until one of the interrupts is triggered.

Comment: you mean directly below the if line? How will it know about $TMP tho?

Comment: Put it **after** the line that assigns to `TMP`.

Comment: It works! Thank you, I didn't know earlier that trap must be put below the `TMP= ` directly. I thought that it will be removed directly.